# Is it possible to flush tqdm output when using nohup

Tags: python, nohup, tqdm

I use the python tqdm package for showing the progress of the execution of my code. Heres a small sample for explaining my use case better

```
progress = tqdm(range(2))
for epoch in progress:
    loss = []
    for i in range(2):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        loss_ = random.random()
        progress.set_description("EPOCH: {}, LOSS: {}".format(epoch, loss_))
        loss.append(loss_)
    loss_mean = sum(loss) / len(loss)
    print("EPOCH: {}, LOSS: {}".format(epoch, loss_mean))
```

When i run this code without nohup, it runs as i expect. it refreshes tqdm descriptions and keeps only the last one on terminal. sample output

```
EPOCH: 0, LOSS: 0.9789279434307936:   0%|                                                 | 0/2 [00:01<?, ?it/s]
EPOCH: 0, LOSS: 0.5650528466113542
EPOCH: 1, LOSS: 0.2959674437384582:  50%|████████████████████▌                    | 1/2 [00:02<00:01,  1.00s/it]
EPOCH: 1, LOSS: 0.39633745424290057
EPOCH: 1, LOSS: 0.2959674437384582: 100%|█████████████████████████████████████████| 2/2 [00:02<00:00,  1.00s/it]
```

however when i run the same code using nohup for running the process in background, all the tqdm descriptions from the inner loop get printed and the outputs of the print statement are printed at the end. Heres the output when using nohup.

```
  0%|          | 0/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
EPOCH: 0, LOSS: 0.6247515429741374:   0%|          | 0/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
EPOCH: 0, LOSS: 0.531051885429166:   0%|          | 0/2 [00:01<?, ?it/s]
EPOCH: 0, LOSS: 0.531051885429166:  50%| ^v^h ^v^h ^v^h ^v^h ^v^h     | 1/2 [00:01<00:01,  1.00s/it]
EPOCH: 1, LOSS: 0.4399544030856224:  50%| ^v^h ^v^h ^v^h ^v^h ^v^h     | 1/2 [00:01<00:01,  1.00s/it]
EPOCH: 1, LOSS: 0.6654644291991813:  50%| ^v^h ^v^h ^v^h ^v^h ^v^h     | 1/2 [00:02<00:01,  1.00s/it]
EPOCH: 1, LOSS: 0.6654644291991813: 100%| ^v^h ^v^h ^v^h ^v^h ^v^h ^v^h ^v^h ^v^h ^v^h ^v^h| 2/2 [00:02<00:00, >
EPOCH: 1, LOSS: 0.6654644291991813: 100%| ^v^h ^v^h ^v^h ^v^h ^v^h ^v^h ^v^h ^v^h ^v^h ^v^h| 2/2 [00:02<00:00, >
EPOCH: 0, LOSS: 0.5779017142016517
EPOCH: 1, LOSS: 0.5527094161424018
```

So I wanted to know if its possible to flush/erase out the previous tqdm outputs from files(keep only the last description) thus mimicking the final output from when executed without nohup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Please understand that under `nohup` you don't have a pty, a terminal,
it just connects `sys.stdout` to the file `nohup.out`.
Normally tqdm does not exactly "erase", rather it prints
a line of progress output followed by `\r` RETURN without `\n` NEWLINE.
Doing that repeatedly gives the visual effect of overwriting same line.
But many characters were output, and they all appear in the text output file.

Your complaint is that "noisy" tqdm output interferes with other output,
and you're hoping to see less noise.
To do that, either add an option to your app so it doesn't call tqdm at all,
or ensure that your app writes its output to some *other* file descriptor.
Then when you `cat` that file you won't see any progress output.

Currently you have

```
from tqdm import tqdm

        ...
        for item in tqdm(items):
            do_stuff(item)
```

You can create your own `def tqdm(...):` wrapper
which conditionally calls the "real" tqdm.
If a user-supplied option or [isatty()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.isatty)
indicate that we don't wish to see progress output,
then your wrapper can choose to silently return
instead of passing through to a tqdm call.

Comment: I do need the tqdm logs as they provide me the execution time data as well. but i suppose i can redirect tqdm logs to another file as you suggested to reduce the noise. thanks

Comment: You have some app-specific requirements, which go beyond the feature set that tqdm offers. So you need a wrapper. That will let you address your multi-environment needs, interactive vs nohup. Your wrapper is in a good position to call `time.time()` to obtain and log the start / end timestamps. Additionally it can notice how many items are processed, perhaps by calling `len()` on a container that is passed in.